# Do the B777x and similar aircraft use ring laser gyros or solid state MEMS gyros?

Tags: boeing

In new generation aircraft like B777x , B787 or A350 use the IRS system which is present is it based on (Ring Laser or Fibre Optics) gyros or they used Solid state MEMS like which our present in our smartphones and G1000 avionics?

Comment: The A320NEO and B737MAX are not new generation aircraft. They are re-engined last generation aircraft. Their IRS is the same as the A320 and 737NG. The newest generation aircraft are A350, B787 and B777X.

Comment: So B777x and  other have same IRS or MEMs

Comment: My point was your question doesn’t make a lot of sense. The 737MAX and 320NEO are not “new” aircraft when you talk about the IRS. I believe there are existing questions that address those systems. You should search ASE before asking a question. If you changed your question to ask about the B787 and B777X, it would be clear and understandable. And you could get a useful answer as they use the Honeywell Earth Reference System. That is a redundant hybrid system that uses both RLGs and MEMs. Edit your question and you’ll have a better chance of getting an answer.